# Getting specific data after crawling websites in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

This is my first Python project, which I pretty much wrote by following youtube videos. Although not well versed, I think I have the basics of coding.

```
#importing the module that allows to connect to the internet
import requests

#this allows to get data from by crawling webpages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#creating a loop to change url everytime it is executed
def creator_spider(max_pages):
page = 0
while page < max_pages:
    url = 'https://www.patreon.com/sitemap/campaigns/' + str(page)
    source_code = requests.get(url)

    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': ''}):
        href = "https://www.patreon.com" + link.get('href')
        #title = link.string
        print(href)
        #print(title)
        get_single_item_data(href)
    page = page + 1

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    print soup
    for item_name in soup.findAll('h6'):
    print(item_name.string)
```

From each page I crawl, I want the code to get this highlighted information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoDYQ.jpg
whose source code is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puk8B.jpg

what I reckon is I should change the attributes of soup.findAll() in the get_single_item_data() functiom, but all my attempts have been futile. Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a javascript site and cannot be crawled. You need to simulate a real browser to crawl these kind of pages. You can try selenium or phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

from bs4 docs

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but the name of the CSS attribute, “class”, is a reserved word in Python. Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument class_:

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
```

However after closer look at the code you mentioned in pic this approach will not get what you want.  In the source I see data-react-id . DOM is build by ReactJS and requests.get(url) will not execute JS on your end. Disable JS in your browser to see what  is returned  with requests.get(url).

Best regards